# Firebase - realtime database set additional value to user throws exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have class User which has additional info, but it is throwing:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead

My code is:

```
User user = new User(Gender.valueOf(mGenderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                            Log.d("GENDER", user.getGender().toString());
                            mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Users")
                                    .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user)
```

The question is how I can still set User.class value or this is not possible?

Comment: please share your pojo class of user.

Comment: there must be the problem in user pojo class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673490/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-serializing-arrays-is-not-suppor)

Comment: Please add the structure of your `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Value type ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)**

- Null values
- Boolean values
- Integer and floating-point values, sorted in numerical order
- Date values
- Text string values
- Byte values
- Cloud Firestore references
- Geographical point values
- Array values
- Map values

> `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead`

- **Above `Exception` show that you have unsupported `Collections` object on User class just change with one of above supported type ex. `List<Type>`.**

**Update**

**Thanks to [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) comment,**

- Above is Data Types is for Firebase [Cloud Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), But Firebase [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) as following.
- Pass types that correspond to the available [JSON types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) as follows:
- String
- Long
- Double
- Boolean
- Map<String, Object>
- List