# Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to upload image and text to Firebase Realtime Database. Below is my code

```
var newList : ArrayList<Bitmap> = arrayListOf()    
         .......

private fun insertSellerItemData(mAuth: FirebaseAuth?) {

        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this@SellItemActivity)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

        progressDialog.show()

        val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid

        val item = Item(tv_title.text.toString(), newList)

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(userId)
        databaseReference?.setValue(item)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(application, "Data successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SellItemActivity, "You cannot register with this mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

**Item**

```
class Item(val title: String,val newList: ArrayList<Bitmap>) :Serializable{}
```

**Error**

```
 Process: com.example.lyner.authentication, PID: 24574
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
```

**Edit**

I convert Bitmap to Uri before store to firebase

```
val lt : ArrayList<Uri> = arrayListOf()
        for(i in newList)
        {
           val list = convertBitmaptoUri(i)
            lt.add(list)
        }
val item = Item(tv_title.text.toString(), tv_desc.text.toString(), tv_price.text.toString(),
                tv_category.text.toString(), dueDate, lt)

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child(userId)
        databaseReference?.setValue(item)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(application, "Data successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SellItemActivity, "You cannot register with this mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
```

**Error**

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:123)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
2019-03-24 12:24:59.268 27163-27163/com.example.lyner.authentication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzi(Unknown Source:253)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzm(Unknown Source:185)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673490/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-serializing-arrays-is-not-suppor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51813160/7666442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store a Bitmap object in Realtime Database without converting it to a string first.  Realtime Database does not make it easy to store binary data.  Consider instead storing the raw binary data in Cloud Storage, and store a reference to that file in the database instead.

Comment: I get  `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` when I convert the bitmap list to Uri

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to compress it or figure out some way to trim it down to something reasonable.  This has nothing to do with Firebase or Google Cloud.

Comment: After I convert Bitmap to String, I was able to upload data to firebase. But when I try  to retrieve them, I get error `Item does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.` Did I miss something in Item class?

Comment: A bitmap that was *truly* converted to a string would be even larger than the byte array it would normally expose.  I think you need to start searching for an answer, maybe post a new question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when I tried to convert `Bitmap` to `Uri`

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

To solve this, I convert it to `String` instead of `Uri`

```
val lt: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
   for (i in newList) {
       val list = bitmapToString(i)
       lt.add(list)
   }

fun bitmapToString(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    val temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;
}
```

And for this error

```
Item does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped
```

I modify `Item` class to this

```
data class Item(
        val title: String = "",
        val newList: ArrayList<String>? = arrayListOf()) : Serializable
```